# Checking indentation, header/class/inline comments, spacing convention

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my code to conform to java formatting convention, I think I've spaced and indented the right way, however, your peer review would be much appreciated.

```
/**
* @author Nad Deb
* Date: 10/10/2020
* This program is used to play two words games
* It will work on input from the keyboard to workout suffix/infix/prefix from words
* derived from a dictionary text file.
*/

package wordgames;

//importing classes for method reading files, CLI input and, exception handling

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class WordGames {
/**
* This method is used to declare and initialize a constant class variable 
* dictionary. create scanner object class, declare string and int variables also
*/


private static final File FILEREADER = new File("DICTIONARY.txt");
private static String[] wordCollect;
private static int wordCounter = 0;
public static Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

/**
* This main method is used to check for file exists with exception handling. 
* dictionary. create scanner object class, declare string and int variables also
*/

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //method for checking if file exists
    if (FILEREADER.exists() == false) {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    wordCollect = new String[100];
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(FILEREADER);
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        wordCollect[wordCounter] = line;
        wordCounter++;
        }
    getSelection();
}

/**
* This get selection method is used to handle input from keyboard against a
* list of options from the menu, which are linked to methods using switch
* case.
*/

static String getSelection() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
    System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
    System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
    System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
    System.out.println("3. Exit.");
    System.out.println("Enter your selections: ");
    String selection = keyboardInput.next();
    
    //case switch for handling menu option input
    switch(selection) {
        case "1": subStringProblem();
        break;
        case "2": pointsProblem();
        break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option.  Try again.");
            getSelection();
    }
    return null;
}    
  
/**
* This substring method is used to concatenate *fix to end of string temp
* which is a string variable input from reading from lines in file via 
* wordCollect variable and checks if wordCollect starts with keyboard input
* substring.
*/
static void subStringProblem() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Substring problem.");
    System.out.println("Enter a Substring:");
    String subString = keyboardInput.next();
    String notFound = " - not found"; 
String infixFound = " - infix";
String prefixFound = " - prefix";
String suffixFound = " - suffix"; 
    for(int i = 0; i < wordCounter; i++) {
        String temp = wordCollect[i];
    
        boolean found = false;
                
        if(wordCollect[i].startsWith(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + prefixFound;
        }
        if(wordCollect[i].endsWith(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + suffixFound;
        }
        if(wordCollect[i].contains(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + infixFound;
        }
        if(!found) {
            System.out.printf(" " + wordCollect[i] + 
                                    notFound  + "\n");
        }
                    else {
            System.out.printf(" " + temp + "\n");
        }   
}
    getSelection();
}

 /**
* This points problem method is used to read file lines from scanner input.
* switch case will check characters= (c) position in word string which is 
* input from nextLine, int l is the word length, for statement checks
* the characters as it goes along the world.  
*/
private static void pointsProblem() throws FileNotFoundException   {
    System.out.println("Points problem.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(FILEREADER);  
    while (input.hasNext()) {
    String word = input.nextLine();
    int l = word.length();
    int point = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 0; x++) {  //checks the letters as it increments
        char c = word.charAt(x);   //checks the letter at position x         
        switch (c) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'l':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
                point += 1;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'g':
                point += 2;
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'm':
            case 'p':
                point += 3;
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'h':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'y':
                point += 4;
                break;

            case 'k':
                point += 5;
                break;
            case 'j':
            case 'x':    
                point += 8;
                break;
            case 'q':                        
            case 'z':
                point += 10;
                break;                       
        }
    }        
    System.out.println(word + "is worth " + point + " points." );
    }
    getSelection();                
}
```

}

Comment: Please make sure the preformatted code block correctly shows all of your code, indented the way you expect. Your class's final '}' is shown outside the code block.

Comment: Regarding indentation: use your IDE's auto-indent or auto-format feature. Nobody does it by hand nowadays.

Comment: WRT your title: please read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: As you haven't edited your question yet, you're probably not interested in a review any more.

Comment: Once a question has been answered, please do not edit the question, especially code that was mentioned in the review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw  I didn't edit in such a way that would alter what the answer addresses.  It was to make the } fit in the code block, which was recommended before an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an automatic formatter like suggested in a comment, or an online one such as this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm or https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer

Some changes that we get are

Before

```
    switch(selection) {
        case "1": subStringProblem();
        break;
        case "2": pointsProblem();
        break;
```

After

````
    switch (selection) {
    case "1":
      subStringProblem();
      break;
    case "2":
      pointsProblem();
      break;

```
````

Comment: Thank you, I have already learnt to use the format function in Netbeans to format my code.

Answer (score 1):

```java
/**
 * @author Nad Deb
 * Date: 10/10/2020
 * This program is used to play two words games
 * It will work on input from the keyboard to workout suffix/infix/prefix 
   from words
 * derived from a dictionary text file.
 */
```

I'd skip such file headers altogether. There are package-level Javadoc, but ideally infomration about author, date etc. would be available through the version control.

---

```java
package wordgames;
```

Ideally, [the package names associate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) with the origin of the software, for example `com.company.application` or `com.github.username.project`.

---

```java
//importing classes for method reading files, CLI input and, exception handling
```

Do not comment what you're doing, comment why and how you're doing it. Such comments are unnecessary as it tells me nothing beyond what I can read from the next three lines.

---

```java
/**
* This method is used to declare and initialize a constant class variable 
* dictionary. create scanner object class, declare string and int variables also
*/
```

Same here, it is even misleading, as there is no method to be seen.

---

```java
private static String[] wordCollect;
private static int wordCounter = 0;
```

You most likely want to use a `List`/`ArrayList` and call it simply `words`. Using a `List` would also allow you to remove the counter.

---

```java
private static final File FILEREADER = new File("DICTIONARY.txt");
// ...
public static Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Ideally the file would be passed to an instance of your class, and you'd open the `Scanner` only in a scope as needed.

---

```java
    if (FILEREADER.exists() == false) {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist.  Exiting.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
```

`System.exit` is a a last resort to exiting a JVM. Returning from `main` would mean the JVM is shutting down, `System.exit` means that the JVM process is being terminated.

---

```java
    wordCollect = new String[100];
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(FILEREADER);
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        wordCollect[wordCounter] = line;
        wordCounter++;
        }
```

Using a `List` here would remove most of the complexity, additionally, reading a file could be done through `java.nio.Files.readAllLines`, which returns a `List` of all lines. You also might need to think about the encoding that is used by the content.

---

```java
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option.  Try again.");
            getSelection();
```

Instead of recursing, you should loop until a valid option is given.

---

```java
static String getSelection() throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Why does this return `String`?

---

```java
    for(int i = 0; i < wordCounter; i++) {
        String temp = wordCollect[i];
```

Could be replaced with a for-each loop when a `List` is being used.

---

```java
        String temp = wordCollect[i];
    
        boolean found = false;
                
        if(wordCollect[i].startsWith(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + prefixFound;
        }
        if(wordCollect[i].endsWith(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + suffixFound;
        }
        if(wordCollect[i].contains(subString)) {
            found = true;
            temp = temp + infixFound;
        }
        if(!found) {
            System.out.printf(" " + wordCollect[i] + 
                                    notFound  + "\n");
        }
                    else {
            System.out.printf(" " + temp + "\n");
        }
```

As an improved exercise, encode the state in a class of its own. The constructor accepts a `String` as value, and there are three `HasPrefix`/`HasSuffix`/`HasInfix` methods which are returning whether these are present. Additionally, the `toString` could be overridden to have it return the wanted String representation.

---

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 0; x++)
```

First, I'm a stubborn advocate that one should never user one-letter variable names, the only exception being dimensions.

Second, choosing `x` as a variable name is misleading, as most of the time one would think it would have something to do with a dimension.

---

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 0; x++) {
```

That's not even working, at all, the condition is wrong.